# CIImage memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, ciimage

I'm using the below method to blur some images.  Using instruments the CIImage's are leaking.  I tried wrapping them in an @autoreleasepool, but no luck.  Any ideas?

```
-(UIImage *)blurImage:(UIImage *)image withStrength:(float)strength
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
        CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
        CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
        [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
        [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:strength] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

        CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
        float scale =  [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
        CIImage *cropped=[result imageByCroppingToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width*scale, image.size.height*scale)];
        CGRect extent = [cropped extent];
        CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:cropped fromRect:extent];
        UIImage *returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage].copy;

        CGImageRelease(cgImage);

        return returnImage;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see the same leak you're seeing when profiling the code. Try this instead which seems to avoid the leak and give you the same results:

```
- (UIImage*)blurImage:(UIImage*)image withStrength:(float)strength
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        CIImage* inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
        CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
        [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
        [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:strength] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

        CIImage* result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
        float scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
        CIImage* cropped = [result imageByCroppingToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width * scale, image.size.height * scale)];

        return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:cropped];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dave, I know it is an old answer but will it still work? I tried this as I am using a similar method but my app is crashing. Is it possible that my return image is being used and if it is not found then the crash happens?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to put CIImages to nil ?

```
-(UIImage *)blurImage:(UIImage *)image withStrength:(float)strength
{      
       //your code
       CGImageRelease(cgImage);

       cropped=nil;
       result = nil;
       inputImage = nil;
       context = nil;

       return returnImage;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I had previously tried setting the CIImages to nil, and that didn't work.  However it looks like setting the context to nil seems to remove the leak.